# How do I make a full width slider in index.html.erb of spree commerce

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, spree

I  add  superlides.js to spree  . The problem is  , when I add slide at  layout  , slides can work fine but it will show  on every page .
Thus , I add slide to  index.html.erb .It work fine but  the slide  is not  show in full  width as  I expected.
So, how do I make a full width slide in index.html.erb ?

Thank in advance.

Comment: I don't know about spree but as you have views folder similar you should have sprees_controller in controllers folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In controller

```
def index
    params.store(:show_slider_top, true)
end
```

In application.erb layout file

```
- if params[:show_slider_top]
    = render :partial => 'welcome/home_screen_top'
```

And when you add it to index file it does not show full page because there will other style applied in layout file